# Cannot find symbol GoogleApiAvailability

Tags: android, google-play-services

I switched from Google Play Services 11.0.4 to 18.1.1 and got the compiler error in the following code:

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()
{
    com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    return resultCode == com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

The error message is:

```
MainActivity.java:246: error: cannot find symbol
        com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
                                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class GoogleApiAvailability
  location: package com.google.android.gms.common
```

Is [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) available in Google Play Services 18.1.1?

In `build.gradle` I have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
}
```

**EDIT1:**

There is `com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight` at least.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it is now `com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight`. At least I was able to compile it.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. After upgrading some Google Mobile Services (GMS) libraries `GoogleApiAvailability` class disappeared.

Looks like Google had been loosening its dependency on GMS recently. I failed to find some useful information across the web, so I decided to look through source code of `GoogleApiAvailability` and try to figure out the difference between `GoogleApiAvailability` & `GoogleApiAvailabilityLight`.

It seems to me that main difference is as follows: `GoogleApiAvailabilityLight` helps to check, yes, availability of GMS services on device, but `GoogleApiAvailability` also helps restore GMS functionality, if broken or outdated. This restoration techniques seem to be aware of GMS & need them. So Google separated 2 classes: one for checking (GMS independent), other - for checking + restoration (GMS dependent).

As my only need was to check GMS's availability - I replaced `GoogleApiAvailability` with `GoogleApiAvailabilityLight` and thats it.

Hope this helps someone who will face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this dependency in your **build.gradle(:app)** -

```
`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"`
```